# Amazon Ec2 and PHP

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-hosting, php5

Some questions about hosting PHP on Amazon EC2.

1. Is this a good option for hosting a PHP website, or should I consider any shared\cheap hosting, like Godaddy, etc?
2. Is the free tier only available for one year? And so, It's only available with the Micro plan?
3. How much would cost one year of EC2 to host a small PHP website? Or, how much would cost a year of a Small Instance of EC2?
4. How does EC2 works? It's like a virtual machine where I setup the OS I want, or is something already configured with a frontend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Infrastructure**

EC2 is mostly an IaaS, *Infrastructure as a Service*, you get a virtual machine, run some OS on it, get root access and install whatever you want etc. They do provided some managed services like databases and load balancers.

**Cost**

You pay per hour for the servers, pay for used bandwidth, disk storage etc individually. You can use this calculator to estimate costs http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

I think the consensus is that EC2 comes at a premium for the flexibility and for being on-demand, so if you need a server that is on 24/7 all year long maybe a normal VPS (paid monthly/yearly) would be more cost effective. EC2 is best for scenarios where you need to spawn lots of servers on and off for some processing, or perhaps to run some website with high load variability.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your answers:

1. Is this a good option for hosting a PHP website, or should I consider any shared\cheap hosting, like Godaddy, etc?

   A. That depends. You can do a lot of tuning and customization according to you if you go for this and not with shared hosting, but at the same time, you need to have knowledge about all that, and should be able to configure it or else you will have to hire someone to do it. Also, does your site serve that much traffic that you are worried about the shared resources.
2. Is the free tier only available for one year? And so, It's only available with the Micro plan?

   A. Yes, Free tier is available only for 1 year, and yes, it's available with only the Micro plan.
3. How much would cost one year of EC2 to host a small PHP website? Or, how much would cost a year of a Small Instance of EC2?

   A. Costing depends a lot on what type of plan you go for. There are different plans with Amazon, like plans which needs commitment for longer time and are cheaper, some which needs commitment for usage of instance and are cheaper again. You can take a look at the plans at [this page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).
4. How does EC2 works? It's like a virtual machine where I setup the OS I want, or is something already configured with a frontend?

   A. Yes, it's like a Virtual Machine where you have to setuo your OS and configure it. It doesn't come configured with a front-end.